# No room from a new dimen with latest TeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, e-tex

And I have a problem when compiling my Latex file

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers
.code.tex)
! No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.25 \newdimen\tikzsiblingdistance
```

Searching on Google, I see that problems come from too many package used, and I should use "etex" package. Although it work with etex, I don't want to use this solution : in fact the compilation works without error on my computer (with Debian 9, last LaTex), and another computer (with debian 7, Tex 2012) the problem appear on a server on Debian 8 we used to compile all latex files.
I want to get the file working like it's working on my PC.
Moreover I saw that it should work with latest version of latex

The Latex version

```
# tex --version
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian)
```

Here is my latex file : [file](https://www.zerobin.net/?b78744c161d14c38#+NPG8KghHt5agsGfoO2iRsKiCyv+PJZ0tJYxz0d4GYc=)

Do you have any ideas ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Commenting the `logo`, I can compile your file without any error. Did you try your code with LuaLaTeX? It usually gives more rooms than pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Welcome! Er ... what do you have against `etex` exactly?

Comment: Note that the reason you don't need `etex` with current LaTeX is because it now uses the extensions enabling extra allocations by default. If you load `etex` with current LaTeX, it does no harm as it checks whether it is dealing with a current version or an older one and proceeds accordingly. All that will happen is you'll see a warning on the console/in the log.

Comment: Your subject says the problem is with the latest TeX, but then you say it works with the latest TeX on your PC, but not an earlier version.

Comment: I don't have any problems other than the logo. You must be defining a dimen inside a macro so that everytime you call that macro a new one is created and run out of dimens.

Comment: you should never use the etex package with a current latex. but on older latex (older than 2015/01/01) the etex package is what you should use.

Answer (score 1):

Found out why.
It seems that latest latex in Debian 8 is LaTex 2014 to the contrary of what latex --version say.

```
$ apt-cache showpkg texlive-binaries
Package: texlive-binaries
Versions: 
2014.20141024-2
```

Which don't enable extra allocation by default.

Just installed manually the latest version, now it works without using etex.